# VIM on windows added ^M character after pasting

Tags: windows, vim, terminal, buffer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi After uninstalling and reinstalling "Windows Terminal" and "WSL" due to issues with installing multiple packages, Vim has started behaving unexpectedly.

When I copy a line and then paste it, Vim adds a `^M` at the end of the line:

```
line^M
```

Subsequently, when I try to add a new line using 'o' or 'shift+o', the indentation is incorrect, as it adds 4 spaces instead of 2:

```
for(...){
  line^M
    _ (<-cursor)
}
```

If I remove `^M`, the indentation works correctly.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Note: I have this .vimrc (I'll paste everything to ensure I don't miss anything important):

```
syntax on
set termguicolors
set background=dark
colorscheme aurora
hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

set noerrorbells
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=
autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb =

set number
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
set nowrap
set t_BE=
"highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=NONE
set cursorline
set clipboard=unnamedplus
"intall vim-gtk o vim-gnome
let s:clip = '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe'  " default location
if executable(s:clip)
    augroup WSLYank
        autocmd!
        autocmd TextYankPost * call system('echo '.shellescape(join(v:event.regcontents, "\<CR>")).' | '.s:clip)
        augroup END
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" The default plugin directory will be as follows:
"   - Vim (Linux/macOS): '~/.vim/plugged'
"   - Vim (Windows): '~/vimfiles/plugged'
"   - Neovim (Linux/macOS/Windows): stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" You can specify a custom plugin directory by passing it as the argument
"   - e.g. `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`
"   - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
Plug 'rafalbromirski/vim-aurora'
Plug 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
call plug#end()
nnoremap<F1> :!./%:r.out < in1 <CR>
nnoremap<F2> :!./%:r.out < in2 <CR>
nnoremap<F3> :!./%:r.out < in3 <CR>
nnoremap<F4> :!./%:r.out < in4 <CR>
nnoremap<F5> :w <bar> !g++ -DLOCAL -o %:r.out % -std=c++20<Enter>
nnoremap<F6> :%y+<CR>
nnoremap<F9> :!./%:r.out<Enter>
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried adding some lines to my .vimrc and using the next command `:set ff=unix` but didn't work.

Comment: That line `autocmd TextYankPost * call system('echo '.shellescape(join(v:event.regcontents, "\<CR>")).' | '.s:clip)` seems related as it appends a `<CR>` to the content of the register and `^M` is one of its representations.

Comment: I tried changing it to an empty string, but didn't work.